# Mongo Replica Set x509 Membership Setup

Tags: mongodb

I have a MongoDB 4.2.1 replica set, that I am trying to setup x.509 membership as documented here

> https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/configure-x509-member-authentication/

In doing so, I get the following error when I start up the mongo process.

> "Error connecting to myserver.subdomain.domain.int:27017
>   (10.82.24.29:27017) :: caused by :: internal error"

I have tried to look at the standard log

> /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log

and syslog and the kern.log but no other errors are showing up

I have verified that the certificate, Issuer, Subject, Subject Alternate Name and the CA chain are valid. I have also verified port 27017 and the certificate is being served is correct with the following command:

> openssl s_client -connect
>   black-duck-data-mart-member-member-3.mia.ucloud.int:27017 -showcerts |
>   openssl x509 -noout -text

and adding grep to verify the SAN

> | grep DNS:

Since the error message isn't very useful, I am looking for a way to troubleshoot this problem.

Here is an example configuration file that I am using

```
# mongod.conf

# for documentation of all options, see:
#   http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/

# Where and how to store data.
storage:
  dbPath: /data/mongodb
  journal:
    enabled: true
#  engine:
#  mmapv1:
#  wiredTiger:

# where to write logging data.
systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  path: /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log

# network interfaces
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 0.0.0.0
  tls:
    mode: preferTLS
    certificateKeyFile: "/etc/ssl/private/mongodb.pem"
    CAFile: "/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt"
    clusterFile: "/etc/ssl/private/mongodb.pem"

# how the process runs
processManagement:
  timeZoneInfo: /usr/share/zoneinfo

security:
  clusterAuthMode: x509

#operationProfiling:

replication:
  replSetName: "replica01"
```

On the bindIp I have also set it to the FQDN and the IP but to no avail.

Any assistance in this matter would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This error came when using the `mongo` client, or when starting the `mongod` process?

Comment: Thanks for the question, I will update my post with how I came up with this error